# how to set a condition so that between the first and second mouse clicks there was a delay not > 500mls

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I have a timer, so it should take a pause by "wait" button press. But button click has own condition. It should be 2 clicks and time between first and second clicks must be not >500mls. So i need to use rxjs operators preferably

```
const observable$ = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(1));
const action$ = new Subject ();
const wait$ = action$.pipe(filter( action => action === false);

const timer$ = merge(wait$, start$)
  .pipe(
    startWith(true),
    // if timer is paused return empty observable
    switchMap(val => (val ? observable$ : EMPTY)),
    scan((acc, curr) => (curr ? curr + acc : acc))        
  )
```

Comment: The "double click" example [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime) may work for you.

Comment: That example is sadly wrong. There is an [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4886) that was raised over two years ago about it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
buttonClicks.pipe(
  bufferTime(500),
  filter((clicks) => clicks.length > 1)
);
```

It creates buffers of events in 500ms windows and then emits when more than one click event is in a buffer.